# Logical equivalence question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$(M \vee B) \wedge (H \vee B) \wedge (H \vee M)$ is a formula where $\wedge$ is the symbol for AND.

What I need to know is: is there any equivalent formula to this one?

Comment: You mean like "((M v B) ^ (H v B) ^ (H v M)) ^ true"?  There's going to be lots, perhaps you're seeking a simplification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(M \lor B)\land (H \lor B) \land (H \lor M)\tag{1}$$

$(1)$ is expressed in **[Conjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)** (CNF), which in some contexts is the desired form and simplification of a proposition. It cannot be further simplified in conjunctive normal form.

$(2)$ Another equivalent form is known as **[Disjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)** (DNF) and is given by:

$$(M \land B) \lor (H \land B) \lor (H \land M)\tag{2}$$

Again, this cannot be further simplified in disjunctive normal form.

You might want to experiment with computing the truth-tables for each of $(1), (2)$ to see that they are indeed equivalent.

NOTE: There are indeed other ways to express the proposition given by $(1)$, but conjunctive normal form and disjunctive normal form are two *very prominent* forms used to express propositions.

Comment: Or note that $(2)$ clearly just says that at least two of $M,B$, and $H$ are true, while $(1)$ says the same thing a little less directly: if at most one of $M,B$, and $H$ is false, then each conjunct of $(1)$ is true, and if at least two of $M,B$, and $H$ are false, then (at least) one conjunct of $(1)$ is false.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU! =1